# Como passar argumento para Objeto prototipado com prototype?

Tags: javascript, instanciar-objeto, protótipo

Com `this` da para fazer isso:

```
function Biscoito(sabor,marca,preco) {
    this.sabor = sabor;
    this.rodas = marca;
    this.preco = preco;
    this.mostrarAtributos = function(){
        return sabor + ", " + marca + ", " + preco;
    }
}

var maizena = new Biscoito("Leite", "Maizena", 1.20);

alert(maizena.mostrarAtributos());
```

Ou seja, da pra definir as propriedades do protótipo DIRETAMENTE na instância através dos parâmetros.

Mas se eu quiser fazer o mesmo construindo o protótipo com `prototype`? Tentei fazer isso e não deu certo :(

```
function Biscoito(sabor, marca, preco) {}
Biscoito.prototype.sabor = sabor;
Biscoito.prototype.marca = marca;
Biscoito.prototype.preco = preco;
Biscoito.prototype.mostrarAtributos = function(){
    return sabor + ", " + marca + ", " + preco;
}

var biscoito = new Biscoito("Leite", "Maizena", 1.20);

alert(biscoito.mostrarAtributos());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No seu primeiro exemplo, nada é definido no protótipo. As propriedades e o método são definidos diretamente na instância criada quando você chama `new Biscoito(...)`.

No segundo exemplo tem os seguintes problemas:

1. Ok definir o método `mostrarAtributos` no protótipo, pois ele pode ser compartilhado por várias instâncias. Já as propriedades não faz sentido definir no protótipo, pois você não quer que todos os biscoitos compartilhem os mesmos valores. Só é útil definir propriedades no prototype se elas forem algo como propriedades estáticas.
2. O seu construtor não faz nada. Você precisaria atribuir os argumentos passados a propriedades do objeto (como fez no primeiro exemplo), ou a propriedades de `Biscoito.prototype` (o que, como eu disse acima, não faria muito sentido).
3. Em `mostrarAtributos`, você tenta acessar `sabor`, `marca` e `preco` como *variáveis*, e elas não existem. Isso está gerando um erro. No primeiro exemplo isso deu certo porque os argumentos passados para a função acabaram capturados (por *closure*) pela função, mas isso não ocorre no segundo exemplo por uma questão de escopo.

Portanto, deixe as propriedades na instância, e o método no protótipo:

```
function Biscoito(sabor,marca,preco) {
    this.sabor = sabor;
    this.rodas = marca;
    this.preco = preco;
}
Biscoito.prototype.mostrarAtributos = function(){
    return this.sabor + ", " + this.marca + ", " + this.preco;
}

var maizena = new Biscoito("Leite", "Maizena", 1.20);

alert(maizena.mostrarAtributos());
```